# undefined array key user

Tags: php, html

I want to ask. when I want to delete user data, an error appears like this, "Warning: Undefined array key "userid" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Proyek22\AdminLTE-3.2.0\pages\tables\delete.php on line 6" is it is there a solution?

this is my delete program :

```
<?php
include 'config.php';



$userid=$_GET['userid'];
$sql="DELETE FROM users WHERE userid=$userid";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($query){
    echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
                (window.alert('User data has been deleted'))
                location.href='index.php'
                </script>";
}
else{
        echo "<script language='JavaScript'>
                (window.alert('User data cannot be deleted'))
                location.href='index.php'
                </script>";
}
?>
```

I tried asking in the Facebook group and didn't get a solution, I hope I can find a solution here

Comment: We shouldn't see `mysqli_real_escape_string` in any modern PHP applications anymore.

Comment: Presumably there was no userID parameter in the URL you used to trigger this php script. Do you understand what $_GET does?